# Block a for loop until a delegate method gets fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm currently working with `CBPeripheralDelegate` to exchange messages between an iOS device and a Bluetooth Low Energy USB dongle. I have to implement the `sendMessage:` method that writes data bytes using a serial emulation service. This method has to send a frame of 15 bytes (or less) at the time, waiting for an ack from dongle before sending the next one.

Below is my code:

```
- (void)sendMessage:(NSData *)message {
    NSArray *chuncks = [self splitMessage:message];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < chunks.count; i++) {
        NSData *chunk = [chunks objectAtIndex:i];
        [self sendChunk:chunk withId:i ofChunks:chances.count];
        // Wait for the ack to be received
    }
}

- (void)sendChunk:(NSData *)chunk withId:(NSInteger)id ofChunks:(NSInteger)count {
    NSMutableData *frame = [NSMutableData new];
    // Here I build my frame, adding header, current chunk ID and total number of chunks, then I call...
    [serialEmulationService writeValue:frame forCharacteristic:serialEmulationServiceCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

Now the issue: the `for` loop within the `sendMessage:` method has to be blocked until the peripheral won't receive the ack, possibly with a timeout. This ack is received inside the delegate method `- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(nonnull CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(nullable NSError *)error`, so here I have to restart the `for` loop previously blocked.

What's the best practice for this particular situation? I'd like to use GCD's semaphores, but I cannot figure out how to implement synchronous calls and cannot manage to understand any of the many online examples that explain this technique.

Could someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about skipping the `for` loop entirely…

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *chunks;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger chunkId;

- (void)sendMessage:(NSData *)message {
    self.chunks = [[self splitMessage:message] mutableCopy];
    self.chunkId = 0;

    [self sendNextChunk];
}

- (void sendNextChunk {

   NSData * chunk = self.chunks.firstObject;

   if chunk == nil  {
      return 
   }

   [self.chunks removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
   [self sendChunk:chunk withId:chunkId++ ofChunks:chances.count];
}    


- (void)sendChunk:(NSData *)chunk withId:(NSInteger)id ofChunks:(NSInteger)count {
    NSMutableData *frame = [NSMutableData new];
    // Here I build my frame, adding header, current chunk ID and total number of chunks, then I call...
    [serialEmulationService writeValue:frame forCharacteristic:serialEmulationServiceCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(nonnull CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(nullable NSError *)error {
    [self sendNextChunk];
}
```

Comment: Easy enough, thank you. The most simple and straightforward approach. Just a little remark: needed to define a property for the original `chunks` array size, since it's decreasing at every chunk sending.

Answer (score 0):

The approach would be to use the `Notification`. Create `separate method` to run your `for loop`. This method will observer for the `Notification`, inside the `delegate` method post the `Notification`. In the `sendMessage:` keep adding the message to a property.